# Overline highlight title h2 with brush effect in css

Tags: html, css, text, effect, underline

I am trying to achieve this on all my subtitles h2 in my whole website (in css) :

[image: h2 overlined with irregular border]

I want to overline my text with this kind of brush effect. It is important for me that the border is irregular and that I get a textured effect.

The most difficult thing is that I want this background to be under the letters only.
What I don't want is a rectangular background that covers the part where there is no letter.
Not that :
[image: I don't want a rectangle]

Unfortunatly it seems only possible with a text in display:inline;

What's complicating even more is that I don't want to decide the last word of each line. The main reason is that I am changing the style at once of hundreds of H2 in my whole site. Changing the html inside each of them would take an eternity and wouldn't be responsive at all.
So changing the html of my h2 like this is not possible :

```
<h2>
<span>Fist line</span>
<span>Second line</span>
<span>Third line</span>
</h2>
```

I tried to play with borders clippath and multiple background-image but nothing worked till now.

Is there a genius here who knows the solution ?

Comment: You have to update the HTML of your `h2` elements for this. You can have a look at [houdini](https://css-houdini.rocks/highlighter-marker-annotations) but support is very limited.

Comment: Unfortunatly I believe changing the html of my all my h2 is not possible. Not by hand. I am looking at houdini and trying to figure out if it could work.

Comment: I looked at houdini but I don't see nothing comparable.

Comment: The site I linked only contains some examples on what is possible, you have to code your specific behavior yourself. Or you have to change the structure of your html. That's the two options you have.

Comment: Well I am still reading what's houdini and how to use it but it seems it's not ready yet as it's apparently not supported on major browsers https://ishoudinireadyyet.com/.
As I told you changing my html structure would be too long and complicated and I don't even see what change would solve my issue as it must absolutly be responsive. I am sure there is an other solution in pure css.